# Search and replace with sed in specific intervall after keyword

Tags: regex, awk, replace, sed, pattern-matching

Assume a textfile `file` that contains some lines with keyword `foo`.

```
> cat file
bar bar baz qux
bar foo bar baz
bar foo qux bar
```

I would like to replace any occurrence of character `r` that occurs between (and including) *n* and *m* characters after the end of the keyword with the character `z`.

Example with *n=1* and *m=3*:

```
> sought_command file
bar bar baz qux
bar foo baz baz  # Replacement only here!
bar foo qux bar
```

Example with *n=4* and *m=6*:

```
> sought_command file
bar bar baz qux
bar foo bar baz
bar foo qux baz  # Replacement only here!
```

Comment: Errr... and where are your attempts? :) Also, I fail to understand the logic: in the first example you replace the 2nd `bar` to `baz` because `r` occurs between 1 and 3 characters after `foo`. But in the second case, the second `bar` contains an `r` that is about 7 characters far from `foo`. Am I understanding this well?

Comment: @fedorqui I think spaces between words are not counted.. so first ex: r is at 3rd pos after foo, 2nd case r is at 6th pos after foo..

Comment: Can the replacement extend over several lines?

Comment: @Sundeep uhms, that makes sense, although spaces are also characters :) As is now, the question is not clear.

Comment: @fedorqui My attempt has been to use `sed` with group specifications like `sed 's/\(foo\)\(r\)/\1z/g' file`, but I freely admit that the code necessary to achieve what I need is out of my league.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this awk script:

```
$> cat mark.awk

p = index($0, kw) {           # only for lines containing keyword
   b = p+length(kw) + 1       # get to next position after kw match
   part = substr($0, b+n, m)  # get substring between start and end points
   gsub(/r/, "z", part)       # replace "r" by "z" only in the substring

   # new reconstruct the original line using substr commands
   $0 = substr($0, 1, b+n-1) part (b+m+1<length($0)?substr($0, b+m+1):"")
} 1                           #default action to print a line
```

Now run this script with your parameters on command line:

```
$> awk -v kw='foo' -v n=1 -v m=3 -f mark.awk file

bar bar baz qux
bar foo baz baz
bar foo qux bar

$> awk -v kw='foo' -v n=4 -v m=6 -f mark.awk file

bar bar baz qux
bar foo bar baz
bar foo qux baz
```

Comment: Thank you! Even though it's not `sed`, it is code that I can understand and edit, if necessary.

Comment: yes, awk is very powerful and awk code is always human readable unlike complex switches in `sed` :)

Answer (score 1):

With sed:

```
n=1;m=3
sed -E ':a;s/(foo( *[^ ]){'"$n"','"$m"'} *)r/\1z/;ta' file
```

Where `:a` defines a label and `ta` jumps to this label until there's no more "r" to replace.

Comment: Isn't this the same as `sed -r 's/(foo.{4,6})r/\1z/'`? It does not work to me for the second case.

Comment: @fedorqui: no it's different since it can perform several replacements (with the loop), about the second example, I think it's a typo, the good values are 4, 7.

Comment: OK. But note you can also use `/g` to perform several replacements if you wish.

Comment: @fedorqui: no you can't use the g in this situation. (cause of overlapped strings. for example "foo rrrrrrrrr"

Comment: This won't work, OP wants to ignore whitespace, also the loop seems pointless you could just use `g` flag.

Comment: I don't follow complex `sed` conditions, but my simple one works here: `sed -r 's/(foo.{4,7})r/\1z/g' <<< "bar foo qux bar and foo qux bar"`.

Comment: @123: no you can't use the g flag, refresh and read my previous comment. I will edit my answer to handle spaces.

Comment: @fedorqui: test it with "bar foo qux rrr"

Comment: You are right. So maybe it should be `foo[^r]{4,7}` instead of `foo.{4,7}`. I don't know, OP accepted an answer that works with 4 and 6, so I don't understand the logic here.

Comment: @fedorqui: now it works with 4,6 (i didn't know that spaces must be ignored)